# An observable or operator that emits parallel streams but always includes the last emission from all streams

Tags: rx-java2

Is there an observable or an Rx operator that can take multiple observables (multiple streams) and present them together in a function and where the most recent emission from each stream is provided? The closest I could find was combineLast but that will only work if all the streams have emitted an item. If I have 4 observables but only 3 have emitted items, I want to see those 3. Of those 3, if one is constantly emitting but the other two haven't emitted anything after some time, I still want to see the last emission from those 2 along with the latest from the one that is constantly emitting.

What I don't want is to have something that combines all the streams into one. They must remain separate.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine them with `combineLatest` and provide a function to wrap the values into a custom class:

```
    Observable.combineLatest(
            source1,
            source2,
            source3,
            source44,
            Function4<String, String, String, String, LatestResult> { t1, t2, t3, t4 ->
                LatestResult(t1, t2, t3, t4)
            })
            .subscribe { latestResult ->
                // Access the latest results here:
                println(latestResult.text1)
                println(latestResult.text2)
                println(latestResult.text3)
                println(latestResult.text4)
            }
}

data class LatestResult(val text1: String, val text2: String, val text3: String, val text4: String)
```

This example assumes all your observables emit strings but you can easily change it.